# MVC Controller not saving data imported in from CSV

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv

I am probably missing something with respect to my understanding of db.savechanges in a MVC controller. So if its something obvious, I apologize in advance.

I am using a MVC controller to import CSV records from a file. The tool I am using is CSVHelper.

I have the following working in code:
1. Calling the file in the view.
2. Executing the actionresult for the importing of records.

The csv file is accessible and is read and turned into a list. And I can tell in debug that all the records are read in to the list and their contents. Here is the code for the actionresult:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportRecords(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string path = null;

        List<ReportsToRecord> RTRs = new List<ReportsToRecord>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\uploads\\" + fileName;
                file.SaveAs(path);
                var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));
                var RTRecordlist = csv.GetRecords<ReportsToRecord>();

                foreach (var r in RTRecordlist)
                {
                    ReportsToRecord RTR = new ReportsToRecord();
                    RTR.Id = r.Id;
                    RTR.REPORTING_ID = r.REPORTING_ID;
                    RTR.TITLE = r.TITLE;
                    RTR.NAME = r.NAME;
                    RTR.REPORTS_TO_ID = r.REPORTS_TO_ID;
                    RTR.EMPLOYEE_ID = r.EMPLOYEE_ID;
                    RTRs.Add(RTR);
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewData["error"] = "Upload Failed";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

When I debug the RTRs.add line it does show all the records successfully read. However the await db.savechangesasync does **NOT** result in these records being saved.

The actual model name for the records being saved ( in Entity Framework) is ReportsToRecord with the controller name being ReportsToRecordsController.

Can anyone see in my code why the RTRs object does contain the records but these do not get saved into the ReportsToRecord model?

The only other thing I can share is that the csv file also contains the key column 'Id'. I dont know whether this is allowed or not for the savechanges operation on the imported records.Normally these keys are generating automatically in m y MVC apps.

As it stands no error comes up. The csv file's  records get read in but just dont seem to be saved back to the database.

Its the typical story.Since no error comes up even in debug, the code is doing exactly what its been asked to do- BUT not what its 'Supposed to' do - which is to carry out the saving to the database.

Any insights would be appreciated. I suspect I am making some stupid error.

Comment: What type (Express, Standard, LocalDb) of database are you running, and where is it located?  How are you subsequently checking to see if the records are written to the database?  Is this something as simple as checking the wrong DB?

Comment: Thanks. Its SQL Server. I don think the database is the problem. The MVC controller brings in the existing reports to records and displays them on the  view. The import csv functionality intended to save to same database. Only one mentioned in web.config- and existing data is retrieveable

Answer (score 0):

dumb error

i changed RTRs.Add(RTR); to

db.ReportsToRecords.Add(RTR);
and it worked